# Run simulation in Modelica for a range in certaing parameter

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am writing a Modelica code for an electrolyser cell and I want to build a Polarization curve as shown in the picture bellow

[image: Polariszation curve of electrolysis]

So the independent variable is the current density, but I don't know how to run the simulation for that variable instead of time. At the moment, I can simulate for a fixed current, which is not very usefull. I am writing all the code, so I am not using components in the Modelica library.

I was thinking of making the current density as a range from, say 0 to 6 (as in the picture), but I am not sure it will work as simulation. Also, I am not sure how I could make that.

Could someone help me with that?
Thanks in advance.
Kind regards.
Vicente.

Answer (score 2):

I guess just run several simulations with different parameters and then plot those on the same plot.

You can use OMPython: https://ep.liu.se/ecp/142/103/ecp17142103.pdf

You can use OMJulia: https://ep.liu.se/ecp/157/072/ecp19157072.pdf

You can use the omc scripting from command line:
https://www.openmodelica.org/forum/default-topic/3353-monte-carlos-simulation.html

Answer (score 2):

If your model does not have any time-dependent aspects (e.g. thermal relaxation) or hysteresis effects, you could reformulate your model so you can vary the current density (which seems to make sense anyway), then you prescribe a varying value for that (e.g. with a `Ramp` block), and then do a [parametric plot](https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/omedit.html#plot-parametric) of the desired quantities vs. the current density.
You can also prescribe a triangle (ramp up, then down) to confirm that there are no hysteresis effects - the curves should overlap.